# SharePoint 2013/2016 Tool to exports sites, lists and sites configuration

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, visual-studio

I'm trying to find a tool to see "enumerated" sites, its lists, a site template configuration and then export it to something like Mindmap or Visio.

Basically trying to find:

- Lists
- Field Types
- Relationships between them

Answer (score 1):

If you want to export SharePoint site, list and document library, you can use the following PowerShell:

```
Export-SPWeb -Identity <SiteURL> -Path <Path and File Name> [-ItemUrl <URL of Site, List, or Library>] [-IncludeUserSecurity] [-IncludeVersions] [-NoFileCompression] [-GradualDelete] [-Verbose]
```

You can also use the SharePoint Central to export them.

About the detail steps, you can refer to [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee428301.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article.

Comment: I'm trying to export the data like a site map sorta.  That contains the lists, field types, relationships between an entire WebApp that maybe has dozens or hundreds of lists into Mindmap or Visio.